# How to receive an input in Spark Streaming only after all partitions in my RDD have been processed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-streaming

Let's say I have a JavaDStreamReceiver which receives an Integer per second from a TCP/IP socket connection in Spark Streaming.
I then store it in a list until I have 100 integers.
After that, I want to divide that RDD into 4 partitions, one per core in my pc, and map these partitions in paralel. So something like this:

```
 public final class sparkstreaminggetjson {
 private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
 private static Integer N=100;
 private static List<Integer> allInputValues= new List<Integer>();

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sparkstreaminggetjson");


  JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

  JavaReceiverInputDStream<Integer> receivedStream = ssc.socketTextStream(
        args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);

  JavaDStream<List<Integer>> storeValuesInList=receivedStream.map( // if N<100, keeps inserting integers; if N>100, inserts the new value into the List and removes the oldest value );

  JavaDStream<List<Integer>> partitionedList=storeValuesInList.repartition(4);


  JavaDStream<List<Integer>> someCalculations=partionedList.map(//some calculations)

  JavaDStream<List<Integer>> otherCalculations=someCalculations.map(//other calculations)

...

finalStream.print();
```

Here is my question. I want to implement a FILO model, in which I receive a new input, place it in the first partition of my RDD and remove the last element from the last partition of the RDD . So basicaly I put and poll integers from my list, keeping the original size. After that I process each partition in parallel as usual.

Here is my problem: whenever my partitions finish being processed, the application return to the `receivedStream`, not to the `partitionedList`. That is, I get a new input per partition, which is not what I want. I want each partition to be processed, and only then go back to the `receivedStream`to get a new input.

How can I do this? Should I replace `map()` after `receivedStream` with some other method to separate stages?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to give an answer, but I realise I could have misunderstood what you asked: could you specify differently what condition should start a new computation?

Comment: @Vale thank you for your answer, but you are right, it's not what I wanted to know. Right now, I have an RDD with 4 partitions, 25 ints in each. What I want is to process every partition and only then receive a new input. As my code is now, each time a partition is processed, I receive a new input (it goes to the receiver, the beginning of my map() methods

Comment: Ideally I want to process each partition in paralel at the same time, in different cores, and only then receive an input. Hope that wasn't confusing

Comment: Now I got it. This is a problem though: The Dstream is only cut by time intervals, given at the beginning of the program. I don't think you can stop the receiving of a new data, unless you signal to your data producer somehow, or you create a personalized receiver wrapping class which starts receiving as soon as a flag is set to true. But even this is kind of unfeasable, for distributed applications, I mean

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood, you could use a window: 1 integer per second means you could use

```
JavaDstream integers = your stream;
JavaDstream hundredInt = integers.window(Seconds(100));
```

This way you will have 100 ints per RDD.

As per the buffering: `newInt ->[1...25][26...50][51...75][76...100] ->lastInt`
This is what I have understood, so if you want to keep the last computation, you could `rdd.cache()` your new 100 ints and elaborate from that.  Either that or `rdd.checkpoint`.